# JavaScript convert little endian string to number

Tags: javascript, binary, endianness

I have a little piece of code that will convert a number to a 32 bit little endian string. That code is as follows.

```
var s = "";
var myNumber = 515
for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    var mask = 1 << i;
    var bit = myNumber & mask;
    s += bit ? "1" : "0"
}

console.log(s);
```

This works fine but I can't seem to figure out how I work back and convert the string back into it's orignal number. Can someone explain how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the same as your conversion to string, but reversed:

```
var num = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i] !== '0') {
    num += 1 << i;
  }
}
```

Or, you could convert the string to an array, reverse it, convert it back to a string, and call parseInt with a base of 2:

```
var num = parseInt(s.split('').reverse().join(''), 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. Two great solutions, especially the first one.